# Wired output by using getline function to read file

Tags: c++, readfile, getline

My program is to read a file which contains some sales records and separate the time, date, price, volume and the rest. Then store each of them in a vector, respectively. The all records are:

> 10/10/2013 04:57:27 PM,5.81,5000,29050.00,LT XT
>
> 10/10/2013 04:48:05 PM,5.81,62728,364449.68,SX XT
>
> 10/10/2013 04:10:33 PM,.00,0,.00,
>
> 10/10/2013 04:10:33 PM,.00,0,.00,
>
> 10/10/2013 04:10:33 PM,.00,0,.00,
>
> 5 rows.

Then my code is:

```
void main()
{
vector<string> date, time, price, volume, value, condition;
int len;

load(date,time,price,volume,value,condition);

len = date.size();

for (int i=0 ; i<len ; i++)
{
    cout << date[i] << endl;
}

cout << "****************************" << endl;

for (int i=0 ; i<time.size() ; i++)
{
    cout << time[i] << endl;
}

}
```

The definition for function load is:

```
void load(vector<string> &object1,
vector<string> &object2,
vector<string> &object3,
vector<string> &object4,
vector<string> &object5,
vector<string> &object6)
{   
    string str1,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6;
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter name of file to read (one word only): ";
    cin >> filename;

ifstream fptr(filename);
if (fptr.rdstate() == 0) // no error open file
{   
    while (!fptr.eof()) 
    { 
        getline(fptr,str1,' ');
        object1.push_back(str1);

        getline(fptr,str2,',');
        object2.push_back(str2);

        getline(fptr,str3,',');
        object3.push_back(str3);

        getline(fptr,str4,',');
        object4.push_back(str4);

        getline(fptr,str5,',');
        object5.push_back(str5);

        getline(fptr,str6,',');
        object6.push_back(str6);
    }
}
else
{  
    cerr << "Could not open file \"" << filename << "\" for reading." << endl; 
}

cout << "- after load function" << endl;
}
```

Then I get the wired result which is below. I don't know where i am wrong.

result for vector date (4 results which should be 5 and mix up everything):

> 10/10/2013
>
> 5.81,62728,364449.68,SX
>
> .00,0,.00
>
> 10/10/2013

result for vector time (same problem):

> 04:57:27 PM
>
> XT
>
> 10/10/2013 04:10:33 PM
>
> 04:10:33 PM

Comment: The concept of a wired result from a program is a bit ... weird...

Answer (score 0):

You never do a `getline` with a `'\n'` as terminator, so this
will be read exactly like any other character, as part of the
"line".

My personal preference here would be to loop reading a complete
line at a time then use `std::regex` (or `boost::regex`) to
separate it up into fields.  This ensures that if anything does
go wrong in one line, you're immediately resynchronized
correctly on the next line.

In other words, the first time you call `load`, when you read
the condition (the last field), you read `"LT XT\n10/10/2013 04:48:05 PM"`.  And the next call to `load`, when you try to get
the date, you will read `"5.81,62728,364449.68,SX"`,  that is to
say, up until the next blank.

Comment: But from my second getline, i use comma to separate the field not space.

Comment: @user3368506 Yes, but not `'\n'`.  The last field should terminate at the `'\n'`, if I understand correctly.

Comment: @user3368506 Actually: if I understand correctly, _every_ field should terminate at a `'\n'`, even if the separator has not been found.  Which can't be done with `getline`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, actually I am not familiar with std::regex so I can't figure out how to read line by line. So, do i need to put some thing to terminate each line?

Comment: I used to do it without using and calling the function, it can work but with the load function, it becomes strange.

Comment: @user3368506 You should learn `std::regex`; it's a very powerful tool.  But in this case, it's fairly simple to do manually as well.  Just use `std::find` to find the next separator, and use the two iterator form of `std::string::assign` to set the return values.

Comment: I have solved the problem by deleting the last comma which is after str6. Now every line can terminate properly.